# Windows can resolve a website but ubuntu18.04, can't

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have been struggling with this for hours ,https://www.montefiorenyack.org/home-care , this website works perfectly fine in windows, but when I switch to Ubuntu 18.04 , dns refuse to resolve it.
I have tried changing the dns , but it does not help, I tried to get the website by directly putting the IP I got from windows machine but that is not working.

What windows is doing which make the website available but does not work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Curiously it works in TOR browser.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 ?, I even tried with IPVanish vpn, did not work.

Comment: On 20.04 where it didn't open either. But it did with TOR Browser.

Comment: It is Not a VPN/IP issue. It will open in your phone too,But not on linux. Edit : On phone only on chrome /brave browser. Firefox same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server [www.montefiorenyack.org](http://www.montefiorenyack.org) has a domain name issue:

```
raj@jarek-02:~$ host www.montefiorenyack.org
www.montefiorenyack.org is an alias for \@.montefiorenyack.org.
\@.montefiorenyack.org is an alias for montefiorenyack.org.
montefiorenyack.org has address 34.224.164.144
montefiorenyack.org mail is handled by 10 us-smtp-inbound-1.mimecast.com.
montefiorenyack.org mail is handled by 11 service20-us.mimecast.com.
montefiorenyack.org mail is handled by 11 service19-us.mimecast.com.
montefiorenyack.org mail is handled by 10 us-smtp-inbound-2.mimecast.com.
raj@jarek-02:~$
```

Someone has defined `www.montefiorenyack.org` as an alias to `\@.montefiorenyack.org`. `\@` is not a valid domain name, therefore Linux DNS resolver library cannot resolve it. Maybe Windows resolver library accepts illegal domain names and that's the reason the domain works on Windows, but not on Linux.

Ask the people who manage the server to fix the DNS issue and create a proper domain name.